Shouldn't we allow questions regarding the Latin language?
Given that an earlier Area 51 proposal 'Latin language' has failed and that a second proposal is currently stuck because of lack of followers, and also considering that Italian is strictly related to Latin (compare the number of questions about grammar, morphology, syntax which can be only understood with reference t Latin), shouldn't we allow questions regarding Latin itself on the site? 
I think yes, at least for the time being, until the Latin proposal reaches the beta phase, which means, never.

I don't think we should transform the site into a Latin discussion one. 
With your kind of reasoning, every site about romance languages could do the same!
I think we should welcome questions that show a clear reference to Latin (and I agree there'll always be a lot of them, for obvious reasons), but we're talking about Italian, not Latin.
So, for instance, etymology may lead us to compare with Latin, as well syntax and phrase construction, this is perfectly fine. Moreover, questions about the history of our language are often prone to furnish answers extrapolating the Latin root.

I think that an italian language site should stick to its original focus: deal with italian language.
If the Latin language site proposal failed it's probably because there is not enough interest by the community.
Of course 'italian language' will deal with Latin related issues when you wnat to explore, etymology, constructions of the phrase and other issues. 
Also, dealing with Latin could bring into the site a whole set of questions which would never be asked in an  "Italian Language" site. 
First, questions related to latin etymology of terms. Second, any kind of historycal questions (imagine questions about latin proverbs which ground their roots in ancient roman history). Third: it paves the way to translations from Italian to Latin....
I'm not sure we want all of them into an italian language site...
